Google Adsense - Third-party cookie will be blocked in future Chrome versions as part of Privacy Sandbox
I have a page which is built by NextJS and integrate with Google Adsense & GA4.
I saw a lot of warning in console log
Third-party cookie will be blocked in future Chrome versions as part of Privacy Sandbox.

I have fixed this warning in react-cookie, but in Google Adsense and GA4, I can't find any solution. I need some suggestion to working on it.
I'm using packages:
    "next": "14.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",

This is my page, you can run F12 and see warning in console. Thanks!!

I tried fix in react-cookie:
setCookie("locale", "en", {sameSite: "none"});

https://community.auth0.com/t/vuejs-third-party-cookie-will-be-blocked-in-future-chrome-versions-as-part-of-privacy-sandbox/136849/5
